# Process explorer crashes when I select all fields

Tags: windows, crash, process-explorer

Sysinternals [process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) crashes when I select all columns. Since the program crashes now, I can't change the settings back. Also I dont know where the program stores this information so I cant change it back to the way it was.

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name: BEX64   Application Name:   procexp64.exe
>   Application Version:  15.31.0.0   Application Timestamp:  51a63bd2
>   Fault Module Name:    StackHash_4321   Fault Module Version:  0.0.0.0
>   Fault Module Timestamp:   00000000   Exception Offset:    0000006f0000006e 
>   Exception Code:   c0000005   Exception Data:  0000000000000008   OS
>   Version:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4   Locale ID:   3081   Additional
>   Information 1:    4321   Additional Information
>   2:    4321760c32b87df21521f3da7736598d   Additional Information 3:    a5a9
>   Additional Information 4: a5a986cae2806a5637aac96253b4278f
>
> Read our privacy statement online:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409
>
> If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our
>   privacy statement offline:   C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open regedit, go to the key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Sysinternals
```

make a backup of this key (Mark is interested in such bad configurations) and delete the complete `ProcessExplorer` key.

Send a [mail to Mark](http://forum.sysinternals.com/program-fault-at-startup-autoruns-112_topic27179_post132645.html?KW=#132645) and attach the bad .reg so that he can repro and fix it.